# OPTIONS request is being sent instead of GET

Tags: http, http-options-method

I am sending a GET request via `text/plain` and the OPTIONS request is sent before that. Why is that so?

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("partner", "root");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("token", "token");
xmlhttp.send();
```

This is how I send it, the request:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

And the error is:

```
Request header field partner is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS . for this `GET` reuest to work without a preflight request, remove `partner` & `token` headers.

Comment: Also: why are you setting "Content-Type" on a GET request?????